# can one turn left or right at a red light with dual lane turns?

Tags: canada, traffic, alberta

The link [Turning | Alberta.ca](https://www.alberta.ca/turning.aspx#:%7E:text=Turning%20left%20from%20a%201%2Dway%20onto%20a%201%2Dway,pedestrians%20crossing%20to%20your%20left.) says "when the light is red, if there are no signs prohibiting the turn, you may turn left on a red light from a one way to a one way after you come to a complete stop at the proper stopping location (stop line or crosswalk) and it is safe. This also applies to dual lane turns. Yield to pedestrians crossing to your left."  It seems it's saying with dual lane turns, one can also turn left on a red light.

However, in this link [Turning lanes | Alberta.ca](https://www.alberta.ca/turning-lanes.aspx) it says "unless prohibited by a sign, at a dual right turn intersection, you may turn right on a red light after you come to a complete stop at the proper stopping point (stop line or crosswalk)." It doesn't mention turning left on a red light.

So can one turn left or right at a red light with dual lane turns? Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, Kentucky has a similar law, again involving one-way to a one-way.

Comment: You can only turn both left and right at any intersection if you cut your car (and potentially yourself) in two – and in most cars, you won’t be able to turn left _or_ right once you do that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out (you are funny)! I have corrected it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The critical consideration is that the permitted left turn must be onto a one-way roadway in that direction. One is not permitted to perform a left turn which involves crossing traffic from the left, which would also imply that it is not a one-way roadway.

Comment: I can imagine a contrived situation where it's the case:  I'm driving north on Main St.  (a one-way street) and I come to the intersection with Park Ave.  To my left, Park Ave. is one-way westbound.  To my right, Park Ave. is a two-way street.  Whether or not any intersections like this actually exist in the province of Alberta is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Intersections of this type are not uncommon in any US city I’ve lived in. They explicitly are not considered one-way roads.

Answer (score 11):

Intersections have a number of possible paths through them. Where those possible paths cross is called a [conflict point.](https://highways.dot.gov/public-roads/januaryfebruary-2003/reducing-points-conflict)

Canada drives on the right.  That means that right turns only do not entail any conflict points, except for a merge into the lane you are joining.   This means you only have three things to watch for: pedestrians, moose, and oncoming traffic in that lane.  That is the rationale behind allowing "right on red" - given the *de minimis* number of conflict points involved,  the driver workload is reasonable.

As a matter of policy they allow 2 lanes of right on red, but that's not your question.

[image]
[source](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/research/safety/04091/10.cfm)

A "left on red" isn't going to work as a general rule, because of a much larger number of conflict points, mostly the worst kind, *crossing* conflict points.   Is this too much workload for the driver? Yes - we know that, because *that was the whole reason why the intersection was upgraded from stop signs to traffic lights in the first place!*  So a *general* left on red is unworkable.

However,  one-way streets to the left create a special situation.  From a one-way to a *leftward* one-way has no conflict points except the "merging" one discussed with right turns.  As such, "left on red" is allowed there.  This is the situation being discussed in your first link.  The first link isn't referring to left turns onto two-way streets.

This isn't relevant to this conversation, but from a two-way to a leftward one-way *arguably* creates this favorable situation again; while there are crossing conflict points, they are only with your own street's traffic which is held by the red light. As such, some jurisdictions allow left turns from a 2-way to a 1-way. **Alberta is not one of them**, probably due to moose :)

The simplest way to think of this is, "you are allowed to turn into the nearest lane to you, if you don't cross any lanes at all", and in Alberta 2 lanes can do this at once.

Comment: Right turn on red, and yes I have heard of the left on red from one way to one way but it is extremely rare in my area, has been the law for decades in many areas. And yet Washington, DC (I'm in Maryland) just changed to outlaw right turn on red to help cut down on pedestrian accidents. Which is a noble cause but since with *any* turn (and actually, even going straight) cars have to yield to pedestrians, it seems a bit much. But I digress. Great answer - watch out for the moose...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: The difference is that when someone is making a right-turn on red, they are looking *left*, and do see pedestrians in front of their own car.  When they're making a right turn on green, they are looking *right*, and do safely see pedestrians.

Comment: @MooingDuck yes -- you notice the USDOT's drawing of "conflict points" that I just added, **does not show** any crossing conflict points for the pedestrian crosswalks.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Your comment implies you missed the point. A right turn has two conflict points: The merge, and the pedestrian crossing. 
Manassehkatz seemed confused that places were banning right-turn-on-red, but the reason for the ban is that when making a right-turn-on-red, the driver looks *away* from the pedestrian conflict point, wheras for right-turn-on-green, the driver looks *toward* all conflict points. Thus right-on-green is far safer than right-on-red, which is why right-on-red is being banned.

Comment: @MooingDuck was just curious and reading through. I'm also in the DC area like manassehaktz. Though I think you have to edit your comment replying to them, as that might be what confused Harper-ReinstateMonica. You put "do see pedestrians" for both cases

Comment: oops, ;you're correct, I typo'd my first comment. When drivers are looking left they do *not* see pedestrians in front of their own car.

Comment: @mooing I grokked the missing "not" in that comment.  I was calling out the myopic, car-centric callousness of USDOT to fail to recognize the existence of that conflict point in their documentation. If it was a freight train, they'd recognize that, because a train is a threat to a car.  I felt that needed no further comment.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact "Washington, DC just changed to outlaw right turn on red" No they didn't. They banned right turn on red at 50 intersections by 2025. There is no blanket ban on right turn on red, it will still be permitted after traffic engineering analysis. Intersections marked "no right turn on red" are not uncommon in cities.

Comment: @user71659 It was reported earlier this year as "no turn on red". I checked now and you're partly correct - apparently 50 intersections now with potentially all by 2025. But given the controversial nature of this, apparently there is acknowledgement that there will likely be some - possibly many - exceptions where right turn on red will still be allowed. So we'll see.

Comment: When "right turn on red" came about in the US in the early 1970s, it was accompanied by a [TV PSA](https://www.oddballfilms.com/clip/13160_13322_psa_rt_on_red) with a catchy jingle whose lyrics went, "Right turn on red after stop, oooh oohhhhh!" (or "oh yeah" or "oooh weeee" or something similar). People have forgotten or don't care that they're supposed to come to a complete stop and look for traffic AND PEDESTRIANS and bicycles before making their turn. Also, at the intersections where RToR is banned, drivers typically ignore the "No Turn on Red" signs anyway.